# Insecure mail. / smtp. subdomains on shared hosts

Tags: .htaccess, security, hosting

(Edit:) How secure are shared hosting solutions?

We have some sites on shared hosting accounts where smtp is accessed as a subdomain e.g. smtp.domain.co.za - when accessing that address with a browser it provides access to a generic login interface to the domain's mail which is not covered by the inexpensive letsencrypt ssl certificates clients who choose shared hosting in the first place typically opt for, leading to security concerns. (E.g. when a security audit gets done).

I expected it should be possible to restrict access to the subdomain, e.g. only allowing access from scripts running in the main domain (or some other consition) with `.htaccess` - these are typically microsites where the only SMTP traffic originates from the site at the domain. However, visiting the 'subdomain' in a browser it seems the .htaccess in the main domain does not get called.

So, short of purchasing a more expensive certificate that either covers the subdomain, or a separate certificate for the subdomain - which would negate the little merit of using shared hosting in the first place, is there a way of resolving the problem?

Comment: Why should paying for a certificate magically make it "more secure"? That is nonsense.

Comment: Also "restrict" by means of "only allowing access from scripts running in the main domain" will certainly _not_ offer real security, but just pseudo security. It is easy to get around such "protection measures".

Comment: Reading this question it is unclear to me what the actual question is. The corner stone of your security measures is your authorization system. Since you apparently keep your services exposed on the internet nothing keeps anyone from attacking that. So your security depends solely on that detail: on how secure _that_ aspect is and how well it is protected itself. And, _obviously_ on those persons you grant access and how responsible they act ...

Comment: Yes. Bit of a catch-22  - relying n the ISP's sec. measures - what they do or don't expose.  For a site that doesn't store sensitive information arguably isn't an issue until a security audit get's done. It specifically flags the SMTP address - actually digging a bit deeper, I think the real issue is "The SMTP server on this host allows the use of weak authentication schemes. ... would give an eavesdropping attacker access to the clear text usernames and passwords of the SMTP server." - I suspect is a given on that hosting level -  get what you pay for... (advising client to upgrade)

Comment: PS. I suppose the question boils down to; how secure are shared hosting solutions?

Comment: Don't get this wrong, but it appears to me like you do not really understand the topic you deal with. That warning you site talks about a SMTP server. That has nothing to do with shared web hosting or a ".htaccess" file.

Comment: If you have the need for another authentication scheme as the one currently provided, then you either need to change that configuration (which you might not have access to), or get the provider to do that or you need to use a different provider or operate it yourself. But don't make the mistake to assume that "cheap" means insecure, that is _not_ the case. I have seen really expensive business solutions on the market I would consider absolute amateurish due to all the beginner mistakes I spotted.

Comment: You want to select a service provider or a hosting provider that offers a solution that fulfills your technical requirements. That has nothing to do with the price tag.

Comment: _"However, visiting the 'subdomain' in a browser it seems the .htaccess in the main domain does not get called."_ - that webmail interface you see when you visit the subdomain in your browser, that is in all likelihood not hosted within your customer folder on the server to begin with - this will be a script the hoster installed in one central location on the server, and _all_ customers `smtp` subdomains will simply route to that directory.

Comment: @arkascha "...do not really understand the topic you deal with..." yes - that's why I ask the question -  :-)

Comment: @AndreClements Sure, absolutely fine and glad that you are not offended. But do you really consider it wise then that you are the one trying to secure your companies IT?

Comment: @arkascha I'm not securing the companies IT - the situation in my case is more specific and nuanced than that - essentially this lies at the boundaries between my responsibilities to my employer and to the actual site owners who are our clients, with various political and business/financial dynamics involved but addressing those I believe would be outside the stated scope of stackoverflow questions - perhaps my question does as well in which case I'm happy to delete it.

Comment: Operating a SMTP server is not really hard. You just have to make your homework. I have been operating my own server for many years now. The advantage: you can chose whatever security setup you want.